# UITableView reloads data when scrolling above the limit

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, reloaddata

I have an issue that i didn't find anywhere on the web (i guess)
I would like to change the text of a cell when i click on a specific button in a UITableViewCell. So i just change the text in the IBAction method, but when i scroll the cell above the y=0 of the TableView, it just gets back to the old text, the text before i clicked on the button. How can i avoid this ? I already set Bounces to no, but didn't work though. I think there is a problem with the reloadData, but I don't see where

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dependent on how you're changing that cell label's text. Every time you scroll back up, your tableview is pulling the information from your data source (as you said, reloadData). If you want to change the cell's text permanently, you will need to change it in the data source and not just temporarily.

Comment: Okay thank you very much ! I have other UITableView issues, do i continue here or do i put another question ?

Comment: I use IBAction and a sender to know on which cell the button is clicked. But i would like a confirm alert, and i don't know how to pass the sender to the action of the buttonIndex.
Second issue : when i hide the button in the contentView, it just hides another button in another cell at random. I use the sender also

Comment: Those are two you can certainly ask in another question, no harm in that. Anyone, including me, will definitely have answers.